# How to determine the compression level of DEFLATE?

Tags: zip, zlib, deflate

There are ten different compression levels for DEFLATE (0 no compression & fastest, 9 best compression & slowest). What is the best way to determine such level for a raw DEFLATE data?

One obvious (yet slow) method would be to try each and compare sequentially. As a side question, is it guaranteed that the size of compressed data for a file is strictly non-increasing going from compression level 0 to 9? If so, binary search can speed up this procedure by a factor of two/three.

Comment: Well... You have an initial size and a compressed size. `compression_level = 1 - (compressed_size / initial_size)`...

Comment: It's not as straightforward as you suggest. For instance, I have a file whose size is 956 bytes, when compressed with level 6 it becomes 324 bytes and when compressed with 9, it becomes 322.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other than the slow method, no.

No, there is not a guarantee that the compressed size is monotonic.  However not being monotonic is pretty rare.

Comment: That's as definitive as an answer to this question gets I suppose =) Thanks!

Comment: By the way, for the slow method you don't need to check the entire deflate stream.  You could just look at the first one or two deflate blocks and probably tell from that.

Answer (score 4):

If you only have compressed data, it does not contain such information. Compression level is only configurable for compression so it's not encoded in the compressed data.

However, if you use something like a zlib, it does add header which includes compression level. From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1950 :

```
  FLEVEL (Compression level)
     These flags are available for use by specific compression
     methods.  The "deflate" method (CM = 8) sets these flags as
     follows:

        0 - compressor used fastest algorithm
        1 - compressor used fast algorithm
        2 - compressor used default algorithm
        3 - compressor used maximum compression, slowest algorithm

     The information in FLEVEL is not needed for decompression; it
     is there to indicate if recompression might be worthwhile.
```

If you don't use library that adds informational header, you could implement it yourself (if that's really needed for your application). It's just a matter of putting extra byte or two (usually) in the beginning.